# Make string of two words having one space

Tags: python, string

I have a file which have

```
hi I am human being I live  for money
```

How my python code can I judge that , `"hi I am human being I live"` is one string and `"for money"` is other string. Logic is if there is one space between words it's a string and two space (tab) means new string start. How to do this in python

Comment: Use the `split()` method with two spaces as the delimiter.

Comment: What's the actual separator, two spaces or TAB? They're not the same thing.

Comment: this is a very deep text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)gular expressions. This way you can split on double spaces and TAB.

```
import re

text = "hi I am human being I live  for money"
re.split('\s{2}|\t', text)
#["hi I am human being I live", "for money"]
```

This will split on double spaces or TABs, if you want something that catches any amount of spaces over 2 and TABs then use: `'\s\s+?|\t'` as your regex.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Will it work for a file having size of 400 mb ?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line of code to [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) your string and get list of strings

```
"hi I am human being I live  for money".split("  ")
#["hi I am human being I live", "for money"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want to do is to `split` your string at instances of double white spaces.

```
def get_unique_strings(text):
    return text.split('  ') # split at a double white space.
```